# Facebook Friends - Real time updates

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I've a server that receives the real-time updates when the users changes their friendships status with other users (for example: userA).

In my database, I've a table named "friendships" where I sync all the user's facebook frienships. So for each request I need to perform a big cycle where:

- I get all friends of userA from facebook
- I have to verify if each of this friends is on my server "Users" table
- Then, I need to check if already exists a friendship between users
- Finally, I can insert a new friendship in database.

So, I'm wondering if there are different approaches to synchronize friendships through Real-time updates.

Comment: which technology or language you are using ?

Comment: I'm using java, hibernate and jetty.